# phpMyAdmin 404 error on Digital Ocean hosting

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, digital-ocean

I'm getting a 404 error after install phpMyAdmin using Digital Ocean's [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-a-lemp-server). I have multiple domains setup on Ubuntu running nginx. There is a phpmyadmin directory within /var/www/. The only difference from the guide was the following command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www`

Do I need to add server block possibly? Since I have multiple domains, each of them has a separate configuration file.

**Sample config file:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name MY_IP_ADDRESS;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root     /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        try_files      $uri /index.php;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I'm not great at server administration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this server block it worked for me.
A basic configuration for phpmyadmin in you case.As you have created a symbolic link in `/var/www`.

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www`

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name website.in www.website.in;
    autoindex on;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
    }   

    location / {
        root /var/www/your/path;
        index index.php index.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            try_files      $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two configuration files for two different domains. So, which configuration file would this live on? Would I need to create a default?

Comment: you can put it in any config file. Just make sure to put both the blocks if 2nd block is not defined for PHP. And let me know if any issue occurs.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 server error after setting both the config files.

Comment: can you share your dummy configuration?

Comment: Sure. Initial post has been updated with the config file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Working on it. And got the error. Once done i will update it.

Comment: @cosmoonot I spent my whole day, but still one by one thing keep on clashing. :( So i recommend you to define a separate config for this. I have update the post for separate phpmyadmin conf nginx. But in future if i found this i will revert you back

Comment: Separate as in a default config file? But where would that live?

Comment: You have to create separate config in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. And make sure in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` this line is `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` is uncommented.

Comment: @cosmoonot I am again changing my post.. Try this one. It worked for me as well.

Comment: What should I name the conf file in /etc/nginc/conf.d/ ?

Comment: you can give any name. but i have updated my post. Please check this is a nested configuration works for both.

Comment: I see, in that case would I need to remove the separate conf files for the two domain that currently exist?

Comment: Yes, need to have two separate config files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` with any name.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for your help. Phpmyadmin works!

Comment: Another question for you. Currently I don't have my DNS pointed for the two domains, with the update to the conf file. How can I test both the domains with just the IP address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136506/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-cosmoonot).

Comment: I was able to edit the host file and both sites with the same IP, but only the first site virtual block is visible, second site is pointing to first site.

Comment: Hey @Sahil-Gulati, any chance you're available to out once again? :)

Comment: I will surely help you out.. Once i get time.. i will be back to you... :)

Comment: Awesome. Let me know when you're available.

Comment: @cosmoonot You there friend, Yes tell me how can i help you.

Comment: just saw your message, my friend. How about this weekend? It's 6:52 AM in Arizona. Maybe we can set a time? That would be awesome!

Comment: @cosmoonot :D there is almost 12:30 difference in our timezone, which time you prefer for me, morning(11-2) and evening(7-11) are okay, generally i am available here in these timings, for this you can decide, in the time being just update your post with your config and question, meanwhile i will look into that..

Comment: Sahil! Lol...Sorry, buddy, when are you available in the next few days? We can exchange emails if you like. Let me know.

Comment: Hey buddy, let me know if you're around this weekend.

Comment: Absolutely. I will gather everything tonight and email you. Thanks! I can add you to Skype or hangouts as well. You rock!